# distribution of r.v. when it's broken down in binomials

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

there is a result I remember being right but I couldn't find it by googling.

Assume A and B indendepent random variable.
I know that when B is fixed (knowing B), A behaves like a binomial law of parameter (p, B).
It follows that A behaves in general like a binomial law of parameter (p, E(b))

Is that true ? is there a "name" for this property ?

Comment: The claim is not true, but perhaps you're recalling that the sum of binomial rvs with the same $p$ but different $n_i$ is binomial? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_sum_variance_inequality

Comment: Except in degenerate cases, it is impossible for such a mixture of Binomials to have a Binomial distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This property is not true. This should be clear even from just reading the statement of the property, since $\mathbb{E}[B]$ need not be an integer.

However, a simple example can also illustrate the point -- let $B$ be a discrete random variable that takes value 0 with probability 0.5 and 1000 with probability 0.5. Whenever $B=0$, then $A=0$. Whenever $B=1000$, then $A\sim\mathrm{Binom}(p, 1000)$. So more than 50% of the time, $A$ takes value 0. Clearly then it is not distributed as $A\sim\mathrm{Binom}(p, 500)$ for arbitrary $p$.